# In TensorFlow, for an image, how do I set value outside a circle be zero?

Tags: tensorflow

What I want to do is like this.

[image][image]

Below is code using numpy. How do I do it using tensorflow functions?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tomopy

output_size = 64
[X, Y] = np.mgrid[0:output_size, 0:output_size]
xpr = X - int(output_size) // 2
ypr = Y - int(output_size) // 2

reconstructed = tomopy.misc.phantom.barbara(size=64, dtype='float32')
reconstructed = np.squeeze(reconstructed)
plt.imshow(reconstructed, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

radius = output_size // 2
reconstruction_circle = (xpr ** 2 + ypr ** 2) <= radius ** 2
reconstructed[~reconstruction_circle] = 0.
plt.imshow(reconstructed, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by multiplication the image tensor with mask tensor. Mask tensor should be a tensor with 1. inside circle and 0. outside. You can pass this mask using placeholder or if the size of all images is fixed, you can define this tensor as tf.constant.

Comment: you can convert a numpy array to tensor with `arg = tf.convert_to_tensor(np_array, dtype=tf.float32)
` If you don't want to write an array for a circle by hand.